# PHP: Regular expression to extract anything between curly brackets

Tags: php

I would like to replace anything between `{{ }}` with it's PHP `date()` equivalent. So, for instance:

`$path = '/some/path/{{m.d.Y}}.txt'`

Would be:

`$path = '/some/path/02.25.2018.txt'`

How could I do this, assuming I need to use a regular expression?

Comment: Start by reading reference about regular expressions with php... preg_replace is what you are looking for and should have found by yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `preg_replace_callback()` :

```
$path = '/some/path/{{m.d.Y}}.txt' ;
$path = preg_replace_callback('~({{[\w.]+}})~', function($matches) {
    return date(trim($matches[0],'{}'));
}, $path);

echo $path ; // /some/path/02.25.2018.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @JROB Please, don't forget to check a green tick to close your question if any answer solves your problem. Thanks :)